# Returning value from Vector throws E0515

Tags: rust

I have recently started to learn Rust and am having a little trouble understanding why I am getting this particular error. I did some Googling to attempt to find a similar issue as mine, but without any luck.

I am trying to make an HTTP call for the yahoo finance API and extract the meta response from one of their endpoints.

Here is my function:

```rust
pub async fn get_history(&self, symbol: &str, range: Interval, interval: Interval) -> Result<&Meta, Error> {
    let mut url = self.url
        .join(format!("/v8/finance/chart/{}", symbol).as_str())
        .unwrap();

    url.query_pairs_mut()
        .append_pair("interval", &interval.to_string())
        .append_pair("range", &range.to_string())
        .append_pair("events", "div,splits");

    let chart = self.perform_request::<Chart>(url).await?;
        
    if chart.chart.result.is_empty() {
        return Err(Error::ErrNoResultsFound);
    }

    let meta = chart.chart.result
        .get(0)
        .ok_or(Error::ErrNoResultsFound)?;

    Ok(meta)
}
```

The error that I am getting is the following:

```bash
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local data `chart.chart.result`
   --> src/finance/yahoo.rs:114:9
    |
111 |         let meta = chart.chart.result.get(0)
    |                    ------------------------- `chart.chart.result` is borrowed here
...
114 |         Ok(meta)
    |         ^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I have other functions already in place, but none of them extract one element from a Vector.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: The vector is dropped and deallocated at the end of the function. If you could return a reference as you do, it would be dangling. The compiler prevents you from doing this. You'll probably have to change your function to return a clone of the data instead.

Comment: Unrelated, but as you might have noticed, checking for emptiness and then accessing the first element is redundant. The `get` method is safe and returns None if the vector is empty, so you can omit the call to `is_empty`.

Comment: Since you're throwing away `chart` anyway, you probably want to move its first element out and return it (not a reference to it).

Comment: TLDR the duplicate: change your function return type to `Result<Meta, Error>` and use `chart.chart.result.remove(0)` instead of `chart.chart.result.get(0)`.

Comment: It does answer @Jmb, thank you for the help here. It worked by changing the meta variable to get a `remove` instead of `get`.

Answer (score 1):

You defined chart inside of the function, so it was allocated on the stack.
Then you returned a reference to chart.chart.result, which references the value on the function stack.
The problem is as soon as the function ends the stack is deallocated, resulting in an invalid value that you returned (invalid pointer).

So Rust is protecting you, you can borrow the a reference inside of the function as long as the stack is valid, but you can't return it outside of the function

A solution to this is to either use Box for chart which will allocate it on the heap. But in that case you need to use take instead of get in order to move the value and not borrow it. Or to simply clone meta